# NameError: name 'players_data' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I got this error. How to define the **players_data**?

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 data = np.vstack((asia[1:], eu[1:], na[1:], oc[1:], sea[1:], players_data[1:]))
>         2 df = pd.DataFrame({data[0, i]: data[1:, i] for i in range(data.shape[1])})
>         3 m = asfloat(data[1:, :4])

NameError: name `players_data` is not defined

```py
asia = open_exl('pubg_as.xls', 0)
eu = open_exl('pubg_eu.xls', 0)
na = open_exl('pubg_na.xls', 0)
oc = open_exl('pubg_oc.xls', 0)
sea = open_exl('pubg_sea.xls', 0)

# Load all data
all_data = np.genfromtxt('PUBG_Player_Statistics.csv', delimiter=',')
all_data[:, 28] = all_data[:, 28] * 100

# Train data
train_data = all_data[1:2000, :][:, [3, 2, 28, 9]]
test_data = all_data[2000:, :][:, [3, 2, 28, 9]]

data = np.vstack((asia[1:], eu[1:], na[1:], oc[1:], sea[1:], players_data[1:]))
df = pd.DataFrame({data[0, i]: data[1:, i] for i in range(data.shape[1])})
m = asfloat(data[1:, :4])
```

Comment: "players_data" variable in your code never used? that is why there is NameError.

Comment: As I can see you are going to use `players_data` in the row `15`. And the error explains it. What kind of data should be present it the array?

Comment: a very large dataset i guess

Comment: i got it from github https://github.com/JunjieCheng/PUBG-hack-detection/blob/master/PUBG_hack_detection.ipynb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to know what was the original value stored in players_data, as this is an incomplete code from another user; however, based on what they were doing, my guess is that players_data is:

`players_data = train_data`

**But, why??**

They used kmeans algorithm to create 6 clusters that represent the following categories:

`['Normal player', 'Waller', 'Experienced Player', 'Both', 'God', 'Aimbot']`

In the first 5 variables used in vstack they have information from the best players in the 5 servers. They wanted used this information, and leverage it with "normal players".

At the end, they didn't use neither "train_data" nor "test_data"; however, in the README.md, they mentioned the following:

> The reason we mix data from the normal data set is to increase the density of normal players, and make the clustering tight. After test, we think 2000 rows of data has the best performance.

An important thing to notice, is that in the train and test data, they selected 4 columns:

`[3, 2, 28, 9]`

Which are the same columns that they used in the "top performers files"

```
def open_exl(address, idx):
    data = xlrd.open_workbook(address)
    table = data.sheets()[idx]
    rows = table.nrows
    ct_data = []
    for row in range(rows):
        ct_data.append(table.row_values(row))
    return np.array(ct_data)[:, :4]
```

Since the code has inconsistencies, it might not be possible to obtain the results as they did; however, it seems as a great opportunity to play with the data and compare the results that you obtain with their previous investigation.